# Django: How to pass variable to include tag from url tag?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

So right now I hardcode to url, which is a bit annoying if you move endpoints. This is my current setup for my navbar items.

```py
# in base.html

{% include 'components/navbar/nav-item.html' with title='Event Manager' url='/eventmanager/' %}
```

```py
# in components/navbar/nav-item.html

<li>
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ title }}</a>
</li>
```

See how I use the url right now?

What I now want is this:

```py
{% include 'components/navbar/link.html' with title='Event Manager' url={% url 'event_manager:index' %} %}
```

But apparently, this is invalid syntax. How do I do it?

If it is not possible, how do I create an app that somehow creates a view where I can pass all the URLs with context variable? In theory, this sounds easy but I'd have to somehow insert that view in every other view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass it as a `variable` not django's `url tag`, use like this:

```
{% url 'event_manager:index' as myurl %}
{% include 'components/navbar/link.html' with myurl %}
```

Now you can pass it to `include` tag.

Answer (score 1):

My solution which fixed it:

```py
# navbar.html

{% include 'components/navbar/nav-item.html' with title='Event Manager' to_url='event_manager:index' %}
```

```py
# nav-link.html

{% url to_url as myurl %}

<li>
  <a href="{{ myurl }}">{{ title }}</a>
</li>
```